# Mac turns off randomly and has lines on screen

Tags: imac

For some reason my iMac keeps turning off around 5 to 10 minutes into boot.

Also just recently it turns on but has shaded lines going down the screen. I have not installed any weird programs and i have not used it in around 3 months.

Any ideas on what the issue is, i don't have any other information about the issue besides whats happening when i use it.
[image: heres a picture of my screen] The image i'm showing you was found on google but this looks exactly like mine does.

The model of my imac is the late 2011 model.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different.  To be helpful, you should include your *specific* model, operating system, etc.  Also, you should try to include a screen shot or a photo of what you are experiencing; remember, we aren't there to look over your shoulder.

Comment: Hi sorry about that allan ill do that now

Comment: I am more inclined to think it's hardware since it's happening *before* the OS gets loaded - meaning doing a reinstall/upgrade will not solve the issue

Comment: Yes i thought at much but before the lines emerged it would just restart every 5 to 10 minutes could that be a hardware issue?

Comment: Ok i will most likely do that on the weekend and post the results then, thank you for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On first guess, based on the description of the symptoms, I would say that you are having an issue with your graphics card.

The best way is to run Apple Diagnostics or Apple Hardware Test. Hold <kbd>D</kbd> while booting from a powered off state.  Run the diagnostics and post your results and I will update my answer.

First update based on the comments:  I found this video on [YouTube](https://youtu.be/9vPM41ZmLos?t=1m45s) that details this exact problem and it's related to the graphics card.  Now, one word of advice: **don't do the fix shown in the video.**

While the diagnosis is correct, that fix is pure nonsense.  I have had much better results getting the board repaired by a shop that specializes in that type of fix ([from eBay](http://www.ebay.com/sch/i.html?_odkw=imac%202011%20video%20card&LH_PrefLoc=1&_osacat=0&_from=R40&_trksid=p2045573.m570.l1313.TR0.TRC0.H0.Ximac%202011%20video%20card%20repair.TRS1&_nkw=imac%202011%20video%20card%20repair&_sacat=0) - I have used the one in Dana Point, CA with great results and for the record, I am **not** affiliated with them).

Normally I would say to replace it, but the prices are ridiculous - sometime over $700 for the graphics card.

Comment: Hi Allan, I will do that, i will be home in a few days will do so then

Comment: Seems like the diagnostics are not running either the computer keeps restarting instead.

Comment: when i hold D on the keyboard nothing happens just keeps restarting, i cant even get to the desktop

Comment: Your Mac came with Snow Leopard (10.6).  If you have the original disks, it will be on Disk 2.  Try booting from that.

Comment: "don't do the fix shown in the video" - well, I fixed 4 video cards that way. It worked for all four of them - so calling it nonsense is nonsense.

Comment: There's a reason you don't heat the whole PCB, thus the specialized equipment to re-flow solder of malfunctioning components  Putting a PCB in an oven to re-flow something not only doesn't fix the underlying issue it damages all the other components.  It's a nonsense fix plain and simple.

Comment: I have fixed for in total 7 '09 - '11 27'' iMacs; 4 of them in the oven, 1 reballed, 2 reflowed. All of them are working fine for more than a year now, not a single one had any problems again so far. Proper reballing is better, no question. But calling a method that works nonsens is nonsens. And baking is a lot better than using a heatgun or anything else you can do at home. It almost always works and lasts for years, by when you will most probably buy a new iMac anyway. Did you actually do it or do you just think it can't work?

Comment: @user2707001 - I worked for a manufacturer and spent time on the manufacturing line and in the rework department.  I was trained by engineers who do this for a living that putting PCBs in an oven is about the worst thing you can do.  This is the mechanical equivalent of using JB-Weld on joint rather than a proper weld and jumping up for joy that "it held."  Good luck with it.

Comment: @Allan Agreed, good comparison. It's like using JB-Weld on a joint rather than a proper weld when you know that the mechanical stress on the joint in this specific device is so low that most probably the JB-Weld will hold it together until you throw it away and you know that a proper fix would be half as expensive as the value of the whole device. You can call it improper, but it is not nonsense.  I don't like it either. But specifically these PCB boards take it really well. I wouldn't recommend doing that generally either. But for this specifically this manufacturing fault it's a working fix.