# Any idea what causes this and if it's fixable ? (iMac 27" 2009)

Tags: imac, performance

I'm trying to fix this late 2009 27" imac 2.66Ghz i5
Hasn't been used for some years now.
It turns on and can be used for a while sometimes until it freezes, randomly it seems and some glitches appear on the screen and it becomes unusable.

[image]

Some other times, it freezes during the boot sequences as in the image below
[image: During boot]

The mouse can be moved, but everything is unresponsive when I try to click or if I type on the keyboard.
Any idea/help is welcome
Thanks

It is running High Sierra.

Comment: had issues like that and it was video subsystem, required replacing mainboard

Comment: I'm hearing both mainboard and gpu, so i don't really know ..

Comment: GPU is integrated into mainboard, so basically all the same. unfortunately they can't simply replace the GPU.

Comment: I see. So i guess i'll just try and find people interested in spare parts then. Don't know if these models are sought-after. Thank for the answers

Comment: Also https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/238569/119271, https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/196870/119271, and https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/281951/119271

Answer (score 0):

I guess your ATI video is dead as it happened to my iMac.
You have an option to replace video card with similar one, which mean that same might happen with new one later or replace it with NVIDIA one that is finally possible, check [here](http://macintoshmen.is-great.net/2019/09/08/imac-2009-to-2011-upgrade-guide/?i=1). Anyway complexity of the procedure is at HIGH mark.